# Cómo obtener datos de un servidor REST con autenticación

Tags: rest, delphi

Resulta que tengo que conectarme a un servidor REST, el cual tiene un método "login" en el que se pide usuario y password, para así obtener un "id", el cual se usará en otros métodos del mismo server.

Tengo en mi formulario los siguientes componentes:  tSimpleAuthenticator, tRestRequest , tRestClient y tRestResponse.

El siguiente código que tengo para autenticar y conectarme funciona bien.

```
SimpleAuthenticator.Username := 'admin@server.com';
SimpleAuthenticator.Password := 'admin';

RESTClient.BaseURL := http://server.com/api/index.xhtml#!/login';
RESTRequest.Execute;
```

Si chequeo el StatusCode del `RestRequest` me da el 200 ok, perfecto.

Este método login devuelve un JSON con un string de autenticación, el cual según la documentación de la API tiene el siguiente formato `{ "id" : "afadkddsf" }`.

Mi consulta es ¿cómo obtengo el string de autenticación que devuelve esa API?

Answer (score 1):

A la pregunta ¿cómo obtengo el string de autenticación que devuelve esa API?.

El string que devuelve la API se recibe en el objeto **RESTResponse1** en la propiedad **content** una vez se ejecuta el request (RESTRequest.Execute). La propiedad content es de tipo string. Puede confirmar el valor recibido agregando un ShowMessage despues de ejecutar el request.

```
SimpleAuthenticator.Username := 'admin@server.com';
SimpleAuthenticator.Password := 'admin';

RESTClient.BaseURL := http://server.com/api/index.xhtml#!/login';
RESTRequest.Execute;

ShowMessage(RESTResponse1.Content);
```

Confirmar que el objeto RESTRequest1 tiene asociado el RESTResponse1 en la propiedad Response.

[image: RESTResponse asociado a RESTRequest]

Comment: Hola Hugo, el código compartido es similar al de la pregunta menos en una línea realmente no parece tener relación con la recomendación. ¿Qué es RESTResponse1? ¿dónde  se  inicializa y cómo funciona? ¿Cómo se agregaría RESTResponse al formulario? Lee [answer] para más información.